# How to change key binding for `yas-expand`?

Tags: key-bindings

`TAB` has multiple key bindings in different conditions. I want to change the key binding for `yas-expand` from `TAB` to `M-TAB`.  How can I do it? Basically I want TAB to run `indent-for-tab-command` in all conditions.

```
TAB runs the command indent-for-tab-command (found in global-map), which is an
interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘indent.el’.
```

---

```
TAB runs the command yas-expand (found in yas-minor-mode-map), which is an
alias
for ‘yas-expand-from-trigger-key’ in ‘yasnippet.el’.

It is bound to TAB, <tab>, <menu-bar> <YASnippet> <Expand trigger>.
```

---

my setup:

```
(defvar my-keys-minor-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (global-set-key (kbd "<tab>") 'indent-for-tab-command)
```

Comment: Have a look at the relevant portion in the source code as of 06/17/2021 (lines 679 and 680):  https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/master/yasnippet.el#L679    After the `yasnippet.el` library loads, you can try removing those definitions with something like this:  `(define-key yas-minor-mode-map [(tab)] nil)` and `(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)`  Then define a new keyboard assignment binding the *variable* `yas-maybe-expand` to your proposed M-TAB using the `yas-minor-mode-map`.  I do not have an opportunity at the moment, however, to test that out ...

Comment: ... continued ... I see that you will likely also have to modify the variable `yas-keymap` which is used while the snippet is expanding ... see the source code as of 06/17/2021 (line 423):  https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet/blob/master/yasnippet.el#L423  There are a few ways to do that ....

Comment: I have added `(define-key yas-minor-mode-map [(tab)] nil);
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil);
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "M-TAB") 'yas-expand)` and seems like it works but I have not done anything related to your second comments. Please have look when you have time

Answer (score 1):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066526/unset-tab-binding-for-yasnippet) you can use:

```
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map [(tab)] nil)
(define-key yas-minor-mode-map (kbd "TAB") nil)
```

This worked for me (using `use-package`) with:

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :ensure
  :bind
  (:map yas-minor-mode-map
        ("C-'". yas-expand)
        ([(tab)] . nil)
        ("TAB" . nil))
  :config
  (yas-reload-all)
  (add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'yas-minor-mode))
```

I remapped `yas-expand` to `C-'`.